# Change src of multiple elements with the same class

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, dom-manipulation

I have multiple iframes, each one with its own `src` attribute;

```
<iframe src="test1.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="test2.html"></iframe>
```

It's specificly a lightbox;
Inside the iframe I have links to other pages.
When you close the lightbox and re-open the lightbox the iframe keeps the last page you visited in that iframe (not the original `src`);

Then I use that code to return the iframe to its original `src`

```
$(".lightboxOverlay").click(function(e) {
  //bla bla bla
  $("#lightboxID iframe").attr("src", $("#lightboxID iframe").attr("src"));
});
```

And it works when you use just one iframe but if you have multiple lightboxes with a diferent iframe each one and use the code above, all the iframes get the same `src`;

As I told before, I need to return the iframes to its original `src` when I close the lightbox.

Can you help me?

The real code is something like this:

```
<div class="lightbox" id="lb1">
    <iframe src="page1.html"></iframe>
</div> 
<div class="lightbox" id="lb2">
    <iframe src="page2.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

**Possible Solution**

Ok, I got a weak solution for my problem.
I add a `active` class to the iframe container when the lightbox is open. Then, when the lightbox is closed, the script uses the ".active iframe" selector.

```
$(".lightboxOverlay").click(function(e) {
  //bla bla bla
  $(".active iframe").attr("src", $(".active iframe").attr("src"));
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
});
```

I know, is a weak solution but if you have a better way to solve the problem, you are free to answer the question.

Comment: Are two frames embed in two diff light boxes with unique IDs?

Comment: There is no way for your code to differentiate between frames, that is why both the frames are getting updated. Try to call them with unique IDs or loop through the available frames.

Comment: <div class="lightbox" id="lb1"><iframe src="page1.html"></iframe></div>
<div class="lightbox" id="lb2"><iframe src="page2.html"></iframe></div>

Y know, I can use the unique id to "reset" the src, but i need a..."globally" way

Comment: Where is this "lightboxOverlay" element that's getting clicked?

Comment: Ok, sorry. Is the class="lightbox" parent (Extended on all the page when the lightbox is open)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got a weak solution for my problem.
I add a ".active" class to the iframe container when the lightbox is open. Then, when the lightbox is closed, the script uses the ".active iframe" selector.

```
$(".lightboxOverlay").click(function(e) {
  //bla bla bla
  $(".active iframe").attr("src", $(".active iframe").attr("src"));
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
});
```

I know, is a weak solution but if you have a better way to solve the problem, you are free to answer the cuestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for your code to differentiate between frames, that is why both the frames are getting updated. Try to call them with unique IDs or loop through the available frames.

```js
var iframes = [...document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')];

$(".lightboxOverlay").click(function(e) {
iframes.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
  /* Your code here and use `element` instead of `$('iframe')` and this will loop through the available frames */
});
});
```

```html
<iframe src="test1.html"></iframe>
<iframe src="test2.html"></iframe>
```